# Pebble: replacing tick_timer_service_subscribe with app_timer_register issues?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I have a watch that updates at non standard time intervals (eg half minutes).
It made sense, to me, to use app_timer_register to update the time which seems to make tick_time_service_subscribe redundant.

Should I expect any issues with the substitution.

So far, the following code seems to be working on CloudPebble.

```
static void timeHandler(void * data){
  find_time_to_next_update(); // updates int time_to_next_update_ms

  app_timer_register(time_to_next_update_ms, timeHandler, NULL);

  update_time(); // refreshes watch face
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm -  every time timer fires next interval will be different/random?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter let nextTime be the time in ms of the next change in time and now be the current time in milliseconds. the alarmTime is nextTime - now. When counting seconds, it has two 500 ms naps at the end and start of every minute around the mid minute. Otherwise it's about 1000 ms. Something similar happens in the minutes mode at the half hour and around midnight. The alarm handle itself increments by one each time a new alarm is set.

Comment: Then yeah timer is a way to go. I think this should be fine.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter does the tick timer service play a roll in adjusting to timezone or user time changes?

Comment: it always sends local time. So in your own timer event you can just retrieve it yourself.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter would time_start_of_today() work as well? (I'll have to wait until December to get my pebble)

Comment: It returns UTC time, if you need it. Oh and do use emulators meanwhile ;) they're fun!

Comment: @YuriyGalanter The pebblecloud emulator is fantastic. Is there a way to mimic a timezone change with it?

Comment: you will need to pass timezone offset from the ouside, Pebble itself doesn't know it. If you'd like - take a look at my Cobblestyle watchface: https://github.com/ygalanter/PebStyle you can import it directly into CloudPebble. You can select a secondary timezone to be displayed on the watch.